# Multiple Event in single click javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom-events

Guys need some help im trying to figure out how can i execute multiple events on single click i am able to change the image on my gallery but i wanted to add some text label on each Img click i need to change each H3 and replace whenever i click the other image, i need to do a multiple event on single click

```js
const current = document.querySelector('#current');
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.imgs img');
const main = document.querySelector('#main-info h3');
const info = document.querySelector('.info');


imgs.forEach(img => img.addEventListener('click', imgClick));


function imgClick(e) {
current.src = e.target.src;

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font: 15px/1.5;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: #567890;
  min-height: 130px;
  border-bottom: 3px #e0480c solid;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

header #branding img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}
header a:hover {
  color: #b9b8b9;
  opacity: 1;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.current a {
  color: #e0480c;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#showcase {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.5)),
    url(/img/enseymada.jpg) no-repeat 0 -400px;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#showcase .main-info {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fffcff;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #ccc;
}

.topinfo {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.info2 {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.foot {
  background: #e24305;
  color: #fff;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-img img,
.imgs img {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: cover;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.imgs {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  background: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper {
  border: #444 solid 3px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.newsletter {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #567890;
}

.newsletter h1 {
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.newsletter .btn {
  display: inline;
  margin: 20px 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}

.newsletter #subscribe {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="main-img">
        <h3 id="main-info">Classic Enseymada</h3> 
        <img src="img/image2.jpg" id="current">  
    </div>

        <div class="imgs">
                <img src="img/image2.jpg">
            <div class="info">
                <img src="img/image3.jpg">
                <h3>Nuttela</h3>
            </div>
                <img src="img/image4.jpg">
                <img src="img/image6.jpg">
                <img src="img/image7.jpg">
                <img src="img/image8.jpg">
        </div>
</div>  
<footer><div class="foot">Copyright &copy Abby Cook's 2020</div></footer>
  <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can call `addEventListener` multiple times, and all the listeners will be executed when the event occurs.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need to set up multiple events, it sounds like you just need to carry out several actions on the one image `click` event. In that case, just add additional statements to be executed after setting the `src`.

Comment: Thanks guys apology for the explanation you guys are right i need to do another action or rather argument to execute the change text.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to pass more arguments to your imgClick function.
One way to do it is to use anonymous functions, something like this should do the trick :

```
    imgs.forEach(img => img.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        imgClick(e, 'param1', 'param2',);
    }));

    function imgClick(e, param1, param2,) {
    current.src = e.target.src;
    // your code
    }
```

Add then your code in the function.